# What are high level and low level device drivers

Tags: devices, drivers

Recently I read that there are two types of drivers (at least for disk), one that are called high level drivers and another called low level device drivers.

Can some one tell me what these are, and why we need drivers in two levels?\

> **A high level device driver places i/o request on queue,after threshold is met a low level device driver will transfer it to disk**

Comment: Do you mean user-space and kernel-space?

Comment: i am not sure,is there device driver in high memory?

Comment: Could you give us a citation to where you read this? May help figuring out exactly what was meant.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Performance Tuning (RH442) Unit 10,page 10

Answer (score 1):

We need two levels of drivers because "there is no problem that cannot be solved by sufficient levels of indirection".

So we don't in fact "need" two levels but computers all want storage that behaves the same so computers all have a "high level disk driver".

Manufacturers want to deliver that data to media in different ways so there are many low level drivers.  It just sort of worked out that way.